Best to have PDA own a System Account or be the System Account to move SOL tokens?
What would be the considerations for choosing between the following?
A) Using a PDA (that is a System Account type) to receive and send SOL tokens on behalf of User A
B) Using a PDA that owns a System Account to receive and send SOL tokens on behalf of User A
I’m trying to figure out why the Solana foundation has the later in this example code.
I’d think safer to just do A since there is no private key involved… Is A just not possible?

Can't delete this but Jon's answer is the correct one.

A. is possible! PDAs define which accounts your program can "sign" for, which is separate from the concept of ownership. This means that your program can manage system accounts for your users at PDAs. You just need to use invoke_signed from within your program using the required seeds. And be sure to avoid assigning the account to your program.
You can read up on PDAs at https://solana.com/docs/core/pda and ownership at https://solana.com/docs/core/accounts#system-program
